# XPath to obtain a node not working in mule esb

Tags: xpath, mule

I have following xml response out of a transformer:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<detailList>
   <details>
      <Id>ID123</Id>
      <personInfo>
        <address>
         <address>All the address</address>
         <city>CITY</city>
         <state>STATE</state>         
         <postalCode>123123</postalCode>
         <country>UNITED STATES</country>        
         </address>
      </personInfo>
      <nameF>NAME1</nameF>
      <nameL>NAME2</nameL>
   </details>
</detailList>
```

I want to obtain the **details** node (including all of its child nodes).
I have used following xpath expressions to get this but all of them are printing blank spaces :-

```
<logger level="INFO" message="#[xpath://detailList]" />
<logger level="INFO" message="#[xpath:/detailList]" />
<logger level="INFO" message="#[xpath:/detailList/*]" />
<logger level="INFO" message="#[xpath://detailList/details]" />
<logger level="INFO" message="#[xpath:/detailList/details]" />
```

The response that gets printed is (blank space after LoggerMessageProcessor) :-

```
INFO  TimeStamp org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor:
```

Everything looks fine but I am puzzled why it is not able to locate the node(s)/element(s) through these xpath evaluators.

Comment: Try `//details`, maybe, the problem with root element

Comment: I already tried that and the result is blank String.

Comment: Which version of Mule are you using? That syntax is deprecated. try using MEL xpath() function or even better xpath3() https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Mule+Expression+Language+MEL

Answer (score 0):

Assume you are using 3.5+ (else use Xpath3()). You can use splitter, soon after that dont keep logger it would provide you empty result like below `org.dom4j.tree.DefaultElement@22a76cce [Element: <details attributes: []/>]`. So use any transformer which is required `dom to xml',  followed by logger will provide the details value. If you dont use splitter, use expression component or whatever you are currently using.

```
 <splitter expression="#[xpath('/detailList/details')]" doc:name="Splitter"/>

<mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer doc:name="DOM to XML"/>
<logger message="****Logger:#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The XPATH you are trying is old and depriciated
You can extract all the values easily using the new Mule XPATH3 :- https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/XPath

for example :-

```
<splitter expression="#[xpath3('//detailList/details', message.payload, 'NODESET')]" doc:name="Splitter"/>
<logger level="INFO" message=" #[xpath3('Id', payload, 'STRING')]" doc:name="Logger"/>
<logger level="INFO" message=" #[xpath3('personInfo/address/address', payload, 'STRING')]" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

and so on ..